# How to make IAP purchase request with free trial period?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, subscription

I am implementing subscription model to my app and I prepared everything. I created a Monthly Subscription product and a Yearly. Also I add a promotional offer for Monthly product. The promotional offer is 1 week free trial.

When I try to purchase the monthly product, It is starting monthly subscription immediately. How can I provide start with trial offer first?

```
let payment = SKPayment(product: MonthlyProduct)
SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
```

Also When I was fetching available products, Only came 2 product (Monthly and Yearly). I know free trial offer under the Monthly product but I couldn't find how to purchase free trial offer.

Comment: You wouldn't have both a monthly and monthly with free trial. You simply have a monthly with free trial. The user purchases that and billing is delayed for a week. If hey cancel during the week then they are never billed and the subscription doesn't renew after a week. Are all three subscriptions in the same group?

Comment: I have a monthly subscription product and I added a free trial offer for this monthly product. I think you did not understand what I ask or You are not know how to do it.

Comment: If you have added the free trial to the existing monthly product then the user just purchased the monthly product and they won’t be billed until after the free trial period

Comment: I know but I asked how can I apply offer to payment request. And I found it and write as answer below. Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is no answer for my question but Someone downvote the question without any comment or objection. Really hard to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found How can I do payment request subscription product with trial period. I have to set payment's `paymentDiscount` with a `SKPaymentDiscount` object.

```
let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
payment.paymentDiscount = SKPaymentDiscount(identifier: <String>, keyIdentifier: <String>, nonce: <UUID>, signature: <String>, timestamp: <NSNumber>)
SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
```

Before we can apply the offer we need to convert our SKProductDiscount into an SKPaymentDiscount. The init method for SKPaymentDiscount provides some clue to what we’ll need to achieve that:

- **identifier** — The identifier of the subscription offer
- **keyIdentifier** — The identifier of the subscription key used to sign the offer
- **nonce** — A throwaway value generated along with the signature
- **signature** — The signature itself
- **timestamp** — The timestamp when the signature was generated.

You can find full process [this tutorial](https://www.saastr.com/ios-subscription-offers/)